# Apache CXf - truncating .xml/.json from @path param

Tags: apache, cxf, truncate

How to avoid truncating .xml from @Path param ..??
example:  http://localhost:8090/testproject/relatedpath/abcxyz123456.xml

In service, we are receiving "abcxyz123456" instead of "abcxyz123456.xml"

Comment: Can you show us some code of your controller?

Comment: @GET
@Path("/relatedpath/{testId:.+}")
public List<Map<String, Object>> relatedPath(@PathParam("testId") String testId); - controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this from your `<jaxrs:server>` configuration to disable debugging options in CXF. See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-Debugging

```
<jaxrs:extensionMappings>
   <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
</jaxrs:extensionMappings>
```